# about typescript handbook: Virtual Directories with rootDirs

Tags: typescript

In the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html), section Virtual Directories with rootDirs, the first example shows that you can imports modules from different source folder by merging different `rootDirs` as one.

```
// File Structure
 src
 └── views
     └── view1.ts (imports './template1')
     └── view2.ts

 generated
 └── templates
         └── views
             └── template1.ts (imports './view2')


// Setting
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDirs": [
      "src/views",
      "generated/templates/views"
    ]
  }
}
```

Notice that you can omit the paths listed in `rootDir` when importing a module.

What I don't understand is the second example.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDirs": [
      "src/zh",
      "src/de",
      "src/#{locale}"
    ]
  }
}
```

> "The compiler will now resolve import messages from `'./#{locale}/messages'` to import messages from `'./zh/messages'` for tooling purposes".

- Why?
- Is `#{locale}` replaced as `zh` in building process?
- Why are we using relative path in `./#{locale}/messages`? What if the importing file is at `src/folderA/`?
- Given that `src/zh` is merged as a rootDir, shouldn't it be `/messages` to import?

The example didn't show the file structure so I'm confused. Looking forward to response. Thanks!

---

## Update 12/21/2017

I'm trying to deduce the folder structure:

```
 src
 └── zh 
      └── messages
 └── de
      └── messages
 └── app.ts (import messages from './#{locale}/messages')
```

According to the first example, all those `rootDirs` will be copied into a virtual `dist` directory so that they are reference each other:

```
dist
 └── messages (zh, de got conflict here!)
 └── app.ts
```

- There should be an conflict! Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will help to explain.

A lot of build or deployment tools allow you to enter a token, and the token will be substituted by the tool later. For example, if I have this line of code in my module:

```
import messages from './#{locale}/messages';
```

The build tool will replace the `#{locale}` token with the value related to the build, for example if I'm building the German version of the app, it will replace it with `de`.

The problem here is that your editor doesn't know the build/deployment tool will do this, so by specifying the tokenized path in your `rootDirs` along with a real path, the compiler and your editor can use the "known" path whenever it comes across the tokenized path.

## Q & A

> Why?

Because a lot of people use tokens for builds, or releases.

> Is #{locale} replaced as zh in building process?

Not by the TypeScript compiler - but by "some other tool". For example, Octopus Deploy has this feature.

> Why are we using relative path in ./#{locale}/messages?

Because this is an example of how to use tokenized URLs. It happens to leverage the `rootDirs` feature.

> What if the importing file is at src/folderA/?

```
import messages from '../#{locale}/messages';
```

> Given that src/zh is merged as a rootDir, shouldn't it be /messages to import?

You *can* still use these folders as root directories... i.e.

```
import messages from 'de/messages';
```

But the example is *really* about how you can tokenize the path:

```
import messages from './#{locale}/messages';
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. As for the second question, isn't the citation in my post misleading? It says "The compiler resolve..."

Comment: I updated my question and thought the `rootDirs` config should result in conflict. May you help explain? Thanks